# Trouble with Xamarin.Android app which communicate with FTDI optical probe via USB

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin, ftdi

I'm trying to realize a Xamarin.Android application which have to communicate with an optical probe via `USB (FTDI chip)`. 
I tried to:

1. Create a java library binding project with Xamarin, to convert [D2XX.jar](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm) in c# equivalent, without success.
2. We have tried to translate in c# parameters of this java instruction 
   connection.ControlTransfer(0x040, 0x03, 0x809c, 0, null, 0, 5000). In C# I found all the parameters except the first one. In c# ControlTransfer accept as a first parameter an enum USBAddressing, that doesn't contain an element with value 0x040 nor 64.
   Has anyone tried to use controlTransfer in the same java-way? How can I translate 0x040 to Xamarin UsbAddressing element?

In advance, thank you very much

Comment: Hi zappasan. Did you find any solution to use ControlTransfer() in c# xamarin? I exactly have the same problem. When I use UsbAddressing.Out it always returns null. Could possibly help me if you fixed it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the only way to use xamarin in this application is to bind a jar.

Answer (score 0):

you can just cast number into UsbAddressing. Now it is only way how to do it and recomended way (I was chating about it with xamarin support). I had same problem and this work for me :

```
 UsbDeviceConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset  mConnection.controlTransfer(0×40, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);//clear Rx
UsbDeviceConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Rx
UsbDeviceConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
UsbDeviceConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 3, 26, 0, null, 0, 0);// baudrate  57600 115200-0x001A-26, 9600-0x4138-16696, 19200-0x809C-32924, 230040-0x000D-13
UsbDeviceConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 2, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// flow  control none                                                            
UsbDeviceConnection.ControlTransfer((UsbAddressing)64, 4, 8, 0, null, 0, 0);// data bit  8, parity  none,  stop bit 1, tx off
```

In my cas I use baudrate 115200 in hexa 0x001A and in int 26

If it still a problem, let me know.

Comment: Majkl: is there any code currently available to connect to wrap the D2xx.jar?  I tried to create a Xamarin android binding library but it blew up with all sorts of errors I didn't understand.